# getting value of <option> with $_POST gives text

Tags: php, html, post, html-select

So, I'm retrieving these options from a database

[image: select and options]

and **I need to retrieve the value but I'm getting the text** in between the tags

```
<option></option>
```

by doing this

```
$inst = $_POST['inst'];
```

therefore if I print $inst I get the "IUTIRLA" for the first option but I need the 41

I don't know what I'm doing wrong... this is how I'm printing the html through php

```
echo "<option value=".$cod_institucion.">".$nombre_institucion."</option>";
```

Comment: You need to put the value inside quotes: `value='".$cod_institucion."'>` As it stands, if it's not quoted, the browser won't parse the value correctly, and you get the text of the option instead of the value you've set.

Comment: @andrewsi Quotes aren't specifically needed for attributes of HTML elements. If there is a space in the value of the attribute then you'll need quotes, otherwise browsers split attributes by the spaces between them and then split the key/value pair on the `=` sign.

Comment: @Jasper - interesting. I guess I've been doing it automatically for so long I just kinda assumed :)

Comment: @andrewsi Me too, I still use them and then let a minifier script take them out when possible. There are more things like this too, for instance `<li>` elements do not need a closing counterparts, browsers just know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you need to correct php code, as it is not parsing the values properly.
Put values under quotes.

```
echo "<option value='".$cod_institucion."'>".$nombre_institucion."</option>";
```

Comment: this is the right one. single quotes must precede the double quotes here. I had no idea though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this

```
echo '<option value="'. $cod_institucion .'">'. $nombre_institucion .'</option>';
```

When outputting HTML, it's going to be easier to use single quotes, that way the double quotes inside your HTML don't have to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have `$cod_institucion` and `$nombre_institucion` backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this...

```
echo "<option value='".$cod_institucion."'>".$nombre_institucion."</option>";
```